# Stripe PHP Payment

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hi i'm trying to follow the stripe guide for an integrated subscription service, here's the code as follows

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51**********');

$app->post('/stripe-webhook', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
  $logger = $this->get('logger');
  $event = $request->getParsedBody();
  $stripe = $this->stripe;

  // Parse the message body (and check the signature if possible)
```

Im just wondering if anybody knows what `// Parse the message body (and check the signature if possible)` actually means.

Comment: Checking the signature is referring to https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures

Comment: In `$event` you should have the parsed body of the request already here. Whether that contains a `message` property now that requires further parsing, don’t know - that probably depends on the context.

Comment: You might want to hide your API key.

Comment: What the api key do ?

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the other 68 lines of that guide in this section [1] you'll see some example code that take the body of the POST request and passes it to the function to `constructEvent()`, effectively parsing the incoming JSON into an Event that you can use in your code.

The signature checking is an optional, but recommended way to make sure that the incoming message was actually sent by Stripe [2]. It works by passing the webhook secret (which you can enable/find in your Dashboard settings for webhooks) to the construct event function along with a signature which is sent as a header. If the sent and calculated (done inside of `constructEvent()` signatures do not match an exception will be raised.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#webhooks

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures

Comment: thanks for your help i've been busy at the moment i will soon have a try